# Android GridView with Adapter

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-adapter, android-cursor

I'm trying to avoid having 5 listviews with individual adapters so the idea is to have GridView which will have 5 columns, representing week schedule, and to attach my CursorAdapter to it. Each row in db has dayId which represents day of the week.

Thing that concerns me is populating GridView in adapter.

Is there any chance to set element to certain column based on provided dayId in cursor row or should I make complete logic for sorting cursor rows before going to adapter?

Comment: i think you have to sort your data according to your requirement

Comment: Sorting isn't the core of the problem because, using sorting, I can handle only scenario where each column has equal number of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to solve this overriding [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html)'s getCount() and getView() methods.

1. Adapter has Cursor field which is get reference on cursor provided in constructor
2. Overriding getCount() so it can pass value which my logic determines from cursor not just cursor size.
3. Overriding getView() so it creates empty elements and checks if that position matches one from cursor field. If it does, then it fills element with data, else it leaves it empty.